# send values to action?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

i am using **struts2**.
Get's all rows selected by the `checkbox` and send them to action?

**My JSP:**

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Example"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,30"
    rowNum="10"
    rownumbers="true"
    multiselect="true"        
>

    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" sortable="false" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="nombre" index="nombre" title="Name" sortable="true" />

</sjg:grid>
```

**//JAVASCRIPT**

```
function ver(){
var s = jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');    
var i, selectedData = [];
alert(s);
if (s.length>0) {
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {            
        selectedData.push(jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid("getRowData", s[i]));                     
    }       
}
```

}

How to send `selectedData` to action?

Comment: A grid column should implement a checkbox model.

Comment: multiselect="true" is active.

Comment: you need like multickecked="true"

Comment: how make to httprequest for strust2?

Comment: Wow, you are needed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749885/action-to-accept-dynamic-json-data-from-user-interface/16752302#16752302)

Comment: function ver(){
 var s = jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'); 
 var i, selectedData = [];
 alert(s);
 if (s.length>0) {
     for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {      
         selectedData.push(jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid("getRowData", s[i]));                           
     }     
 }
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "test",     
     data : selectedData,
     dataType:"JSON",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });  
}

Not working for me y.y. What need? .jar?

Comment: Not working is a usual thing, because you didn't try it. Programming is not easy thing. You need some more time to get realized. And jars, ofcourse you need if you haven't yet, read the answer carefully.

Comment: But I thought you will do it without ajax, aren't you?

Comment: I am trying in every way possible with or without ajax ... e.e
Not working for me $.ajax and XMLHttpRequest u.u

Comment: This is the same, Ajax. I thought you need HttpRequest.

Comment: function http() {
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
   client.open("POST", "test.action");
   client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
   client.send(null);
 }

not work >.<...